# Select data string in returned JSON POST before adding to DOM jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, object

Found a whole lot of questions on json, nothing specifically asking this (unless I missed it somewhere):

After a JSON request, I have string that comes back with some HTML in it:

Returned data:

```
'<div class="set1">Set1</div><div class="set2">Set2</div><div class="set1">Set1</div><div class="set2">Set2</div>'
```

On success, I'm setting my data (string) into a jQuery object like: $(data).

How do I actually go about pulling out: Set1 out of that object? Is that even possible?

Quick example:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "posting to get some json data back",
  data: data,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
      var newData = $(data);
  }
});
```

Where would I go from here if I want to look at the `.text()` of `div.set1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is jquery's `filter`.

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

"Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test."

```
$(data).filter('div.set1').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you passed your HTML to the jQuery constructor, it is now a regular jQuery collection (even though you have not yet added it into the DOM).

Hence, you have access to all of jQuery's regular functions:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "posting to get some json data back",
  data: data,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
      var newData = $(data).filter('div.set1').text();
  }
});
```

Comment: .find() came back as an empty string. .filter() did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: @spez86: Totally right. Did not realize that your `div`s were not enclosed in a single parent `div`. Updated.